# I am unable to change or remove pattern color of SVG in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I am using Adobe Illustrator CC 22.1 (64bit).

When I open a SVG that has a pattern I am unable to change the color of the pattern. Sometimes it works but with this pattern it doesn't, I do not know what I am doing differently.

[image]

Inside the pattern there should be negative space.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your layers panel it looks like it's a compound shape that may have been released.

You should be able to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select the patterns and use pathfinder option "Minus-Front" to get your cutouts.

[image]